# Raspberry Pi's as Enterprise and RADUIS Mesh

Tags: networking

I am thinking of using a couple of PI3's to create a mesh network for a small part of the office. The current AP's use 'WPA2-Enterprise' and use a RADIUS server on the sites Server 2012 domain controller.

I have made PI's access points in the past away from work but I can't seem to find any documentation on creating them with authentication like this with the enterprise and radius wifi authentication method. This connection and method has already been setup on the main wifi AP/controller that is made by ASUS

Please could someone help?

Comment: *"I can't seem to find any documentation"* -> Stop using "raspberry pi" in your search terms.  The brand of hardware is mostly irrelevant.